# featherlight.js first picture clicked in gallery doesn't have navigation arrows

Tags: gallery, featherlight.js

I'm using the [featherlightGallery](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/blob/master/gallery.html) add on for [featherlight.js](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/).
It works OK except when I click on the 1st image in a set, the image opens but not as a "gallery". In other words, there is no "next" navigation button.
If I click the 2nd (or later) image, the gallery opens and I can click next and forward as expected.

```
<div class="tidy">
    <div class="pfTitle" data-fid="12">
            Photos-Misc
            <div class="tih"><img src="img/upload.png" class="tup" alt="upload" title="upload"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tpHolder">
        <div class="tiWrap">
        <div class="tiLink" data-imglink="ANNAWAN/Photos-Misc/100_0708.jpg">
                    <img src="../data/towerFiles/ANNAWAN/Photos-Misc/100_0708.jpg" 
                                class="ssImg Photos-Misc" title="Photos-Misc"                           
                                data-featherlight-gallery="Photos-Misc" 
                                data-featherlight-target-attr="src">
        </div>
        <div class="tiDel"><img src="img/x.png" class="ssImg delTpic" title="delete"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tiWrap">
        <div class="tiLink" data-imglink="ANNAWAN/Photos-Misc/IMGP6500.JPG">
            <img src="../data/towerFiles/ANNAWAN/Photos-Misc/IMGP6500.JPG" 
                     class="ssImg Photos-Misc" title="Photos-Misc"           
                        data-featherlight-gallery="Photos-Misc" data-featherlight-target-attr="src">
        </div>
        <div class="tiDel"><img src="img/x.png" class="ssImg delTpic" title="delete"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tiWrap">
        <div class="tiLink" data-imglink="ANNAWAN/Photos-Misc/IMGP6501.JPG">
                <img src="../data/towerFiles/ANNAWAN/Photos-Misc/IMGP6501.JPG" 
                         class="ssImg Photos-Misc" title="Photos-Misc"
                         data-featherlight-gallery="Photos-Misc" data-featherlight-target-attr="src">
        </div>
        <div class="tiDel"><img src="img/x.png" class="ssImg delTpic" title="delete"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a thumbnail is clicked (bound to class *tiLink*) , this function is run:

```
// obj is the object (image thumbnail) that as clicked
function tiLink(obj){
        var ilink=$(obj).data("imglink");
        if( !ilink ){return;}

        // var viewLink="../data/towerFiles/"+ilink;        
        var gal=$(obj).find("img").attr("title");

        // single view
        //$.featherlight(viewLink); 

        // gallery view
        $("."+gal).featherlightGallery({
                previousIcon: '&#9664;',     /* Code that is used as previous icon */
                nextIcon: '&#9654;',         /* Code that is used as next icon */
                galleryFadeIn: 100,          /* fadeIn speed when slide is loaded */
                galleryFadeOut: 300          /* fadeOut speed before slide is loaded */
            });     
}
```

One other note: the image data is loaded and created dynamically.
Why doesn't the 1st image have prev/next navigation if it is chosen first?

EDIT: the "non-gallery" problem happens with whatever picture I click first in the set.

EDIT #2:
[JSFiddle demonstrating the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/5bmyswLk/19/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're over complicating things. You have a single gallery, just bind it once. Call something like this *once*:

```
$('.tiLink').featherlightGallery({targetAttr: 'data-imglink', ...})
```

If you have multiple independent galleries, bind them individually, probably something like:

```
$('.gallery').each(function() { $(this).find('.item').featherlightGallery(...) })
```

Comment: Actually there are multiple groups of images. The class "tidy" above would be duplicated about 10 times with different groups of pictures.

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem

Comment: Yes that did it. After the objects were created, I had to bind them all. I wasn't binding them until a picture was clicked, so the first one didn't get bound.